# Huffman coding for an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the Huffman coding for the `<img>` in html, I have a JavaScript function that generates Huffman coding and it takes a string as input, so I need to convert the image in the `<img>` into a string somehow, get the Huffman coding and output it in the html.

My problem converting the `<img>` to a string, I've searched a lot but I still don't know how to proceed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why are you doing this? JPEG images _already_ use Huffman encoding.

Comment: See: [Get image data in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a canvas like this

[How to get base64 encoded data from html image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760764/how-to-get-base64-encoded-data-from-html-image)

Ultimately you need the image converted to base 64, Which can either be done server side or client side if supported

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

You can then huffman encode the base 64