# Fetching images with JavascriptResponse in CefBrowser (Without downloading twice)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, image, cefsharp

I'm attempting to use [`CefSharp` (Offscreen)](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.OffScreen) to get image information in a webpage. I'd like to avoid downloading the content twice (I'm aware I can pull the src string from an image tag, and then download the image again). Right now, this is my code:

```
using (var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://example.com"))
{
    //All this does is wait for the entire frame to be loaded.
    await LoadPageAsync(browser);

    var res1 = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src");
    //res1.Result = the source of the image (A string)

    var res2 = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]");
    //This causes an APPCRASH on CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
}
```

The way I figure it, `CefSharp` is already downloading these images to render a webpage. I'd like to avoid making a second request to pull these images from the client, and pull them directly from the client. Is this possible? What are the limitations of the `JavascriptResponse` object, and why is it causing an APPCRASH here?

Some thoughts: I thought about base64 encoding the image and then pulling it out this way, but this would require me to generate a canvas and fill that canvas every time for each image I want, generate a base64 string, bring it to c# as a string, and then decode it back to an image. I don't know how efficient that would be, but I'm hoping there could be a better solution.

Comment: as far as i know, you will not be able to get the actual image back from the DOM. Your base64 solution is the most appropriate one here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
result = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
;(function() {
    var getDataFromImg = function(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '');
    }

    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    var finalArray = {};
    for ( var i=0; i<images.length; i++ )
    {
        //I just filled in array. Depending on what you're grabbing, you may want to fill
        //This with objects instead with text to identify each image.
        finalArray.push(getDataFromDiv(images[i]));
    }
    return finalArray;
})()");

    //Helper function for below
    private static string FixBase64ForImage(string image)
    {
        var sbText = new StringBuilder(image, image.Length);
        sbText.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
        sbText.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        return sbText.ToString();
    }

    //In c# convert the data to a memory stream, and then load it from that.
    var bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(image));
    var streamBitmap = new MemoryStream(bitmapData);
    var sourceImage = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(streamBitmap);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try executing this javascript...

[How to get base64 encoded data from html image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760764/how-to-get-base64-encoded-data-from-html-image)

CefSharp should have FileReader api.

Then you can have the EvaluateScriptAsync call return the base64 encoded image data.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. Was just a wonky workaround.